# Custom http header for MapBox IOS SDK with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

How to add custom http header value when making tile request to any wms service with Swift?

I've seen a few examples written in OBJECTIVE-C that are said to work, but I haven't been able to do it with swift.

I tried to set the MGLNetworkConfiguration.sharedManager.sessionConfiguration.httpAdditionalHeaders value, but I couldn't see the http headers I sent in the requests.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you added your `httpAdditionalHeaders`, where exactly in your setup do you do this?

From the docs [MGLNetworkConfiguration](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/6.3.0/Classes/MGLNetworkConfiguration.html#/MGLNetworkConfiguration)

> Assign this object before instantiating any `MGLMapView` object, or using `MGLOfflineStorage`.
>
> **NOTE**
>
> `NSURLSession` objects store a copy of this configuration. Any further changes to mutable properties on this configuration object passed to a session’s initializer will not affect the behavior of that session.

Here's what you can try -

```
let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
sessionConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = [:] // your headers here
MGLNetworkConfiguration.sharedManager.sessionConfiguration = sessionConfig
```

And make sure this call happens in the app before instantiating any `MGLMapView` object, or using `MGLOfflineStorage`.

Comment: Is this working for you, I still get failure on at my end ?